# Name for the ability or inability to "look without seeing"

Tags: word-choice

In certain disciplines it's important to be able to see something without paying attention to it or pointing it out in order to respect privacy.

Think like when IT looks at your computer - you might have your email open, but they don't read it. A person without this ability might work on your computer and make comments about emails they see.

Comment: we often use "discretion" to talk about such things, but that's not exactly what you're after. "Conscientious" seems to imply if not describe it. Disinvestment of focus?

Comment: *Professional detachment* , seems a good fit.

Comment: I call it four o'clock on a Friday :-)

Comment: How would *ignore* fall short?